# mysql select from a view with where condition gives different result than executing the view definition with where condition

Tags: mysql, database, view

I have a view with the following definition:

```
    select 
        `cb_trans_detail`.`numero_partida` AS `numero_partida`,
        `cb_trans_head`.`fecha_partida` AS `fecha_partida`,
        `cb_trans_detail`.`concepto_partida` AS `concepto_partida`,
        `cb_cuenta`.`nombre_cuenta` AS `nombre_cuenta`,
        `cb_cuenta`.`codigo_mayor` AS `codigo_mayor`,
        `cb_mayor`.`nombre_mayor` AS `nombre_mayor`,
        `cb_mayor`.`categoria` AS `categoria`,
        `cb_categoria`.`nombre` AS `nombre`,
        `cb_categoria`.`presentacion` AS `presentacion`,
        `cb_trans_detail`.`codigo_cuenta` AS `codigo_cuenta`,
        sum(`cb_trans_detail`.`debito_partida`) AS `Debitos`,
        sum(`cb_trans_detail`.`credito_partida`) AS `Creditos`,
        `cb_cuenta`.`saldo_inicial` AS `saldo_inicial`,
        ((`cb_cuenta`.`saldo_inicial` + 
       sum(`cb_trans_detail`.`debito_partida`)) - 
       sum(`cb_trans_detail`.`credito_partida`)) AS `Saldo`,
        concat(`cb_mayor`.`categoria`,`cb_cuenta`.`codigo_mayor`,`cb_trans_detail`.`codigo_cuenta`)
 AS `Codigo` 
      from 
        ((((`cb_trans_detail` join `cb_cuenta`
      on(((`cb_trans_detail`.`codigo_cuenta` = `cb_cuenta`.`codigo_cuenta`) 
      and (`cb_trans_detail`.`categoria` = `cb_cuenta`.`categoria`) 
     and (`cb_trans_detail`.`codigo_mayor` = `cb_cuenta`.`codigo_mayor`)))) 
     join `cb_mayor` on(((`cb_cuenta`.`codigo_mayor` = `cb_mayor`.`codigo_mayor`) 
     and (`cb_cuenta`.`categoria` = `cb_mayor`.`categoria`)))) 
     join `cb_categoria` on(((`cb_mayor`.`categoria` = `cb_categoria`.`categoria`) 
     and (`cb_trans_detail`.`categoria` = `cb_categoria`.`categoria`)))) 
     left join `cb_trans_head` on((`cb_trans_detail`.`numero_partida` = 
     `cb_trans_head`.`numero_partida`))) 
      where 
        (`cb_categoria`.`presentacion` = '1')
        group by  concat(`cb_mayor`.`categoria`,`cb_cuenta`.`codigo_mayor`,
        `cb_trans_detail`.`codigo_cuenta`)
```

If I select from this view as follows:

```
SELECT 
  `balance_general_view`.`numero_partida`,
  `balance_general_view`.`fecha_partida`,
  `balance_general_view`.`concepto_partida`,
  `balance_general_view`.`nombre_cuenta`,
  `balance_general_view`.`codigo_mayor`,
  `balance_general_view`.`nombre_mayor`,
  `balance_general_view`.`categoria`,
  `balance_general_view`.`nombre`,
  `balance_general_view`.`presentacion`,
  `balance_general_view`.`codigo_cuenta`,
  `balance_general_view`.`Debitos`,
  `balance_general_view`.`Creditos`,
  `balance_general_view`.`saldo_inicial`,
  `balance_general_view`.`Saldo`,
  `balance_general_view`.`Codigo`
FROM
  `balance_general_view`
WHERE
  `balance_general_view`.`fecha_partida` BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-01-31'
```

this yields a different result than if I execute the query as follows:

```
select 
    `cb_trans_detail`.`numero_partida` AS `numero_partida`,
    `cb_trans_head`.`fecha_partida` AS `fecha_partida`,
    `cb_trans_detail`.`concepto_partida` AS `concepto_partida`,
    `cb_cuenta`.`nombre_cuenta` AS `nombre_cuenta`,
    `cb_cuenta`.`codigo_mayor` AS `codigo_mayor`,
    `cb_mayor`.`nombre_mayor` AS `nombre_mayor`,
    `cb_mayor`.`categoria` AS `categoria`,
    `cb_categoria`.`nombre` AS `nombre`,
    `cb_categoria`.`presentacion` AS `presentacion`,
    `cb_trans_detail`.`codigo_cuenta` AS `codigo_cuenta`,
    sum(`cb_trans_detail`.`debito_partida`) AS `Debitos`,
    sum(`cb_trans_detail`.`credito_partida`) AS `Creditos`,
    `cb_cuenta`.`saldo_inicial` AS `saldo_inicial`,
    ((`cb_cuenta`.`saldo_inicial` + sum(`cb_trans_detail`.`debito_partida`)) - sum(`cb_trans_detail`.`credito_partida`)) AS `Saldo`,
    concat(`cb_mayor`.`categoria`,`cb_cuenta`.`codigo_mayor`,`cb_trans_detail`.`codigo_cuenta`) AS `Codigo` 
  from 
    ((((`cb_trans_detail` join `cb_cuenta` on(((`cb_trans_detail`.`codigo_cuenta` = `cb_cuenta`.`codigo_cuenta`) and (`cb_trans_detail`.`categoria` = `cb_cuenta`.`categoria`) and (`cb_trans_detail`.`codigo_mayor` = `cb_cuenta`.`codigo_mayor`)))) join `cb_mayor` on(((`cb_cuenta`.`codigo_mayor` = `cb_mayor`.`codigo_mayor`) and (`cb_cuenta`.`categoria` = `cb_mayor`.`categoria`)))) join `cb_categoria` on(((`cb_mayor`.`categoria` = `cb_categoria`.`categoria`) and (`cb_trans_detail`.`categoria` = `cb_categoria`.`categoria`)))) left join `cb_trans_head` on((`cb_trans_detail`.`numero_partida` = `cb_trans_head`.`numero_partida`))) 
  where 
    (`cb_categoria`.`presentacion` = '1') and `cb_trans_head`.`fecha_partida` BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31'
  group by 
    concat(`cb_mayor`.`categoria`,`cb_cuenta`.`codigo_mayor`,`cb_trans_detail`.`codigo_cuenta`)
```

My question is: How to get the result I need using the view and filtering programatically instead of hard-coding the where condition? Thank you. If you need the individual table definitions let me know. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a left join to a table X and a condition in the `WHERE`-clause to this table X, you change your left join to an inner one. If you want to restrict the results by the values of this left joined table, you must use this condition in the `ON` clause of the left join instead:

```
...
LEFT JOIN 
    cb_trans_head 
ON
    cb_trans_detail.numero_partida = cb_trans_head.numero_partida
AND
    cb_trans_head.fecha_partida BETWEEN '2014-01-01' and '2014-01-31'
...
```

If there's another one that I overlook, tread it the same way.

Comment: I made the change to the view definition and selected from it using the where condition as outlined above. The result is the same, it does not work. Thanks.

Comment: @alfredocole In your view there isn't a restriction on this column. It's only in your single query without a view that my answer is valid.